# Edit C Compiler used in MySQLdb Python

Tags: python, mysql, macos, osx-lion

I am trying to install MySQLdb 1.2.3 on Mac OSX Lion 10.7.3. When I run

$ sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" python setup.py build

An error is thrown that says:

```
 gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
    -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -                I/usr/local/mysql/include -  I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -arch i386
unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

I saw [this similar forum post](http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=91002&sid=7ed20b931baa7c66ab61c525edadd81f) but noticed that MySQLdb 1.2.3 does not include a user_config.py.

My question is, which .py file can I edit to change 'gcc-4.2' to 'gcc'? This could likely fix the problem.

Comment: you can easily find this out yourself by doing simple `grep -e 'gcc-4.2' -R *` in the source directory. Or even `ack gcc-4.2`, if you have `ack` installed.

Answer (score 1):

Meh.

```
CC=gcc python setup.py ...
```